# Установка wine x32 на Debian 9 x64

Tags: debian, wine

При попытке установки wine32 на Debian x64 пишет следующее(выполняю `apt install wine32`) :

```
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово 
Некоторые пакеты невозможно установить. Возможно, вы просите 
невозможного,
или же используете нестабильную версию дистрибутива, где запрошенные 
вами
пакеты ещё не созданы или были удалены из Incoming.
Следующая информация, возможно, поможет вам:

Пакеты, имеющие неудовлетворённые зависимости:
wine32:i386 : Зависит: libwine:i386 (= 1.8.7-2) но он не будет 
установлен
E: Невозможно исправить ошибки, у вас отложены (held) битые пакеты.
```

Multiarch включал так : `dpkg --add-architecture i386 && sudo apt update`

Comment: А что если принудительно прописать `apt install wine32 libwine`?

Comment: Пишет, что libwine самой новой версии уже установлен, а зависит от libwine:i386

Comment: ну так поставьте конкретно `libwine:i386`

Comment: @alexander Если ставить libwine:i386 то пишет: `Пакеты, имеющие неудовлетворённые зависимости:
 libwine:i386 : Зависит: libfontconfig1:i386 (>= 2.11) но он не будет установлен
                Зависит: libglu1-mesa:i386 но он не будет установлен или
                                libglu1:i386
                Зависит: libpulse0:i386 (>= 0.99.1) но он не будет установлен
                Зависит: libx11-6:i386 но он не будет установлен
                Зависит: libxext6:i386 но он не будет установлен
                Рекомендует: libgl1-mesa-g` и еще что-то но это не влазит

Comment: *у вас отложены (held) битые пакеты* — `$ sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Прописал `sudo apt-get -f install`, ничего не произошло, `обновлено 0, установлено 0 новых пакетов, для удаления отмечено 0 пакетов, и 234 пакетов не обновлено.
`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Wine x64 устанавливается, а wine32 - не хочет